# get All Custom Fields using Jira-Client

Tags: node.js, jira, jira-rest-api

I want to get all custom Fields  of a jira issue using jira-client . I am using nodejs and module jira-client. i am unable to get all custom fields attributes of a jira issue . Pls suggest a way to get all custom fields .

tried getIssue(SAS-13654) or searchJira() methods but dont have any method for getting all custom fields at one go like getCustomFields() using jira-client

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

The Jira Rest API shows for a `fields` parameter value of "`*all`" that will return the value of all fields on the specified issue that you have access to, including custom fields.

[jira-client's `findIssue` method](https://github.com/jira-node/node-jira-client/blob/master/src/jira.js#:%7E:text=@name%20findIssue) will send the fields parameter as "`*all*`" by default. Therefore, you *should* be able to access all fields via

```js
findIssue('SAS-13654');
```

or, if the multiple parameters are required,

```js
findIssue('SAS-13654', undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined);
```